# A discrete probability distribution, but the population is continuous vs. discrete

Tags: probability, terminology

Suppose we have some sort of discrete distribution as follows:

| fruit | frequency |
| --- | --- |
| apple | 0.3 |
| orange | 0.5 |
| tomato | 0.2 |

This is a statistical description of the actual population, which is

```
orange, apple, tomato, apple, orange, apple, orange, orange, orange, tomato
```

That is, the actual population consists of discrete items belonging to each category. It has a meaningful "size" (10) and its members cannot be subdivided. Of course, the same distribution could arise from a population of 100 fruit. For the purposes of this question, the overall population is unspecified, but it is assumed to be "knowable" in the sense that we could go out and count how many fruit there are.

Compare the following, identical distribution:

| road material | frequency |
| --- | --- |
| dirt | 0.3 |
| asphalt | 0.5 |
| gravel | 0.2 |

This is a statistical description of the road that runs from Smallville to Bigville. The road is ten miles long, but it isn't organized in ten neat segments (`dirt, dirt, dirt, asphalt, asphalt ...`). Instead the road shifts arbitrarily between materials, so it is impossible subdivide it into segments such that each segment consists of only one material. Imagine something like this, but with fractal complexity:

[image]

**What term can I use to differentiate between these two kinds of population structures?**

It seems appropriate to refer to the road as a *continuum,* but I'm not sure what term to use for the fruit. I want to say *discrete,* but this invites confusion because *both* of the probability distributions shown above are discrete (taking one of only three values).

Answer (score 1):

According to [the English Wikipedia page for "Probability space"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_space), it seems that both examples would have a finite "event space", but the "sample space" is finite/discrete in the first case, and a continuum (in various senses) in the latter case.